# What do these anagrams have in common?

Tags: knowledge, anagram

> - Raw Rats
> - Indonesia Jan
> - Plantain Lee
> - A Unsaddled Mirror
> - Delta Sir

What do these anagrams have in common?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The anagrams are:

> Star War (sic), Indiana Jones, Alien Planet *(thanks, hexomino!)*, Radioland Murders *(thanks, dcfyj!)*, and Red Tails.

They are all

> directed by, produced by, or otherwise involved with George Lucas.

Comment: For ther 3rd one: nyvra cynarg (rot13)?

Comment: the last one you're missing is: Enqvbynaq Zheqref (also rot13)

Comment: All of the solved ones are correct, also the third one answer consists of two words.

Comment: @Deusovi two minutes till I can accept and look up the fourth answer, it's spelled wrong. Good job otherwise!

Answer (score 3):

**The anagrams are:**

> Water Arts, A ninja onside, Leap An Inlet, Slat ride

**The thing they all have in common is:**

> Obscure recreational activities/sports

Comment: The first one doesn't work, there isn't an "e" and there is already a correct answer, but plus one for creativity!

Comment: Woops, I guess I can change the first one to Tsar War haha. Now I am reaching.